# Raspicam C++ API mmal linking

Tags: camera, raspicam, c++

I have installed the raspicam API as instructed here: http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40

It appears to be installed correctly.

When I compile any programs linking libmmal I get the errors:
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmmal
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmmal_core
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmmal_util

I have tried updating the pi and reinstalling the API but I just can't get it to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ldconfig -p | grep libmmal`.  On raspbian you should get:

```
    libmmal_vc_client.so (libc6,hard-float) => /opt/vc/lib/libmmal_vc_client.so
    libmmal_util.so (libc6,hard-float) => /opt/vc/lib/libmmal_util.so
    libmmal_core.so (libc6,hard-float) => /opt/vc/lib/libmmal_core.so
    libmmal_components.so (libc6,hard-float) => /opt/vc/lib/libmmal_components.so
    libmmal.so (libc6,hard-float) => /opt/vc/lib/libmmal.so
```

If not, add to your question the contents of the few short files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`.  If you are not using raspbian, you should give your OS.

---

This means the relevant libraries are available on the system and if you build an executable linking them, there should not be a problem.  However, there may be a problem building the executable; in this case it seems when `gcc` invokes the linker, `/opt/vc/lib` is not in its path even though it is in the runtime loader path (they are not quite the same).  If you use `gcc -v`, you'll see there are some non-standard paths being used as options (e.g., `/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf`), but not that one.  However, you can specify it yourself:

```
gcc test.c -L/opt/vc/lib -lmmal
```

Should work. You can also:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/vc/lib
```

This variable is probably not predefined but you'll see those other paths added to it in `gcc -v` output.  Note it is **not** the same as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which is used by the runtime loader.

Comment: I get exactly this output

Comment: Hmm, I just downloaded v0.1.1 and test compiled it following the instructions from that page; `make` seems to have completed without error.  There's a `.so` in `build/src` and some tests in `build/utils`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear I'll update the question - the error is when I compile a test program. So anything of the form: g++ -o out main.cpp -lraspicam -lmmal -lmmal_core -lmmal_util

Comment: Okay, the issue is the difference between the paths used by the compile time linker and the runtime loader ;) I've added a few paragraphs about that.